# How to get different max id from database at a time

Tags: android, sql-server, database

hello i am creating an hotel app in that when i am inserting order into database at that time i am fetching max orderid from database and inserting order and orderid in database. but my problem is that when i am installing that apps in two different devices at that time when i am placing order at time it gets same orderid to different table and insert into database and order is inserted in one table so please give me any solution

```
    private void openAlert(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayActivity.this);
    new AsyncLoadOrderId().execute();
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Restrosoft");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    // set positive button: Yes message
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // go to a new activity of the app

            for (int i = 0; i < user_fName.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(user_fName.get(i)); //prints element i
                menulists = user_fName.get(i);
                if (tabletypes.equals("A/C")) {

                    getAcrate(menulists);
                    getTotalamount(menulists, convertedvaluefororderid);
                    getmenuidofperticular(menulists);
                    getButtonfinalordertodb();
                    String conquantity = String.valueOf(quantity);
                    new AsyncInsertIntoTemp().execute(menulists, conquantity, OrderIdFromService, WaiterName, str1);
                } else if (tabletypes.equals("Non A/C")) {

                    getProfilesCount(menulists);
                    getTotalamount(menulists, convertedvaluefororderid);
                    getmenuidofperticular(menulists);
                    getButtonfinalordertodb();
                    String conquantity = String.valueOf(quantity);
                    new AsyncInsertIntoTemp().execute(menulists, conquantity, OrderIdFromService, WaiterName, str1);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            Insertingintotableorder inserttableorder = new Insertingintotableorder(OrderIdFromService, str1, currentDateTimeString, intentfromTwolistwid, ordertype, tablestatustblord, discvaluefortblord, discamount);
            new AsyncCreatetableOrder().execute(inserttableorder);
            new AsyncCreateTemporder().execute(OrderIdFromService, KOTIDFromTwolist, str1, "", "", WaiterName);
            ForupdateStatus updatestatushere = new ForupdateStatus(str1);
            new AsyncupdateStatus().execute(updatestatushere);
            Intent intents = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intents.putExtra("Uname", WaiterName);
            intents.putExtra("ForButton", cntforb);
            startActivity(intents);
            mHelper.remove();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "Successfully inserted...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // set negative button: No message
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // cancel the alert box and put a Toast to the user
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    // set neutral button: Exit the app message
    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Exit the app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // exit the app and go to the HOME
            DisplayActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show alert
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Here is async task:

```
 protected class AsyncLoadOrderId extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        //ArrayList<UserOrder> subTablea = null;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try {

                jsonObj = api.GetOrdertopid();
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


                //subTablea = parser.parsOrderid(jsonObj);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("AsyncLoadDeptDetails", e.getMessage());

            }
            return jsonObj;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Value");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                }
                OrderIdFromService = jsonObj.getString("order_id");
                convertedorderid = Integer.parseInt(OrderIdFromService);
                orderidfortable.setText(OrderIdFromService);

                if (intentresponse.equals("Yes")) {

                     serveroid = String.valueOf(orderid);
                    orderidfortable.setText(serveroid);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();


            }


        }
```

Comment: Show one of Async classes, AsyncCreatetableOrder() for example

Answer (score 1):

Your Async work is completely wrong

For example if I call

```
new AsyncLoadOrderId().execute();
```

And then immidiatly click "Yes" button of your `AlertDialog` I will get wrong results because `OrderIdFromService` can have **previous** value. In other words `OrderIdFromService` gets value **after** `AsyncLoadOrderId()` will do its work but other actions are synchronious. With slow/bad internet connection that will not work at all.

So this line

```
new AsyncInsertIntoTemp().execute(menulists, conquantity, OrderIdFromService, WaiterName, str1);
```

Doesnt do anything because `OrderIdFromService` probably has wrong value.

So you should do it in chain like

1. `AsyncLoadOrderId()`
2. wait for its done
3. get value and run `new AsyncCreatetableOrder()` **inside**
   `AsyncLoadOrderId().onPostExecute()`;
4. wait until `AsyncCreatetableOrder()` is done
5. get value and run  `new AsyncCreateTemporder()` inside `AsyncCreatetableOrder().onPostExecute()`
6. etc

Its the one way to do it with your `AsyncTasks`.

Usually developers use something like `rxJava` for same functional